# AndroidStudio - Trocar url por imagem em local path do projeto

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho uma string que uso para setar a imagem de alguns botões:

```
 String imagem[] = {"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12121.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/0555555.jpg"};
```

Baixei as imagens e salvei no diretório src\main\imagens dentro do projeto.

Como posso substituir na string acima a url pelo path local?

Segue o código detalhado:

No meu **onCreateView**:

```java
mAdapter = new ModuloAdapter(lista(), getActivity());

private List<ItemModulo> lista() {

    String titulo[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

    String imagem[] = {"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/19/20/01/5555.jpg",
              "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/11/23/24/5554.jpg",
              "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/08/05/29/44141.jpg",
              "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/08/05/29/4412241.jpg"};

    for (int i = 0; i < titulo.length; i++){
            ItemModulo item = new ItemModulo();
            item.setLista(lista[i]);
            item.setImagem(imagem[i]);
            itemList.add(item);
    }

    return itemList;
}
```

Comment: Detalha mais como você está setando a imagem nos botões

Comment: editei com mais detalhes

Comment: Ainda to meio confuso, o que você quer é que em tempo de execução o aplicativo irá baixar as imagens pro aparelho, e essas imagens salvas será usada no botão?

Comment: não eu vou usar a imagem já baixada e colocada no drawable
porém não estou conseguindo usar a imagem direto somente com o link....gostaria de colocar o local path da imagem na string ao invés da url

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o certo é deixar imagens do projeto na pasta drawable e alterar a nomenclatura dela pra não começar com número:

src/main/res/drawable

Você pode chamar as imagens da seguinte maneira:

```
        //adiciona suas imagens em um array de inteiros ao invés de String
        int[] imagem = new int[]{R.drawable.imagem1, R.drawable.imagem2, R.drawable.imagem3};
```

Logo, no seus getters and setters altera o setImagem e o getImagem para `int`

no seu `for` para enviar a lista mantém o mesmo

Agora aqui vai o truque, na hora de recuperar esse inteiro da imagem faça o seguinte:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(item.getImagens());
```

Utiliza esse drawable pra setar a imagem no botão.

A classe R é responsável pela comunicação entre xml e java, e o diretório drawable onde fica armazenadas as imagens do projeto.

Comment: Espero que tenha o ajudado, qualquer dúvida só falar, e se a resposta foi útil pra vc, marque-a como útil ou como respondida. Abraço

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo. mas não consegui fazer assim funcionar. traz a imagem em vazia. Eu utilizo a string da seguinte maneira tenho um array com os nomes e o array aí de cima com as imagens. A imagem está no drawable
for (int i = 0; i<tipo.length; i++){
            ItemModulo item = new ItemModulo();
            item.setRecipe(tipo[i]);
            item.setImg(img[i]);
            itemList.add(item);
        }

Comment: @user147627 eu editei minha resposta, se ainda não tiver conseguindo, edita sua pergunta e coloca como você tá recebendo essa imagem no getImagem e e enviando para o botão. Eu fiz um projeto simples com 3 exemplos diferentes com o mesmo resultado, caso queira comparar com seu código me avisa que coloco no github e mando aqui na minha resposta.